# How to store a const string at a memory location in Microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, c, flash, rom

I have two questions

1. > ```
   >   #define PORTBASE 0x40000000
   >   unsigned int volatile * const port = (unsigned int *) PORTBASE;
   >   *port = value; //write to port 
   >   value = *port; // read from port
   > ```

   Can I use the above method to store a value at desired memory
   location and access it?
2. How can I store, for example, a software version information 
   string(V1.2AG4ML) in the same way at a location?

   SPC5 32-bit controller is used.

Regards,
Joe

Comment: How you do this typically depends on the compiler, but no your example code would not generally work for this at all.  In some more purely Harvard architectures like an AVR data access to flash memory may also require special keywords to trigger generation of special instructions.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can only use that method to write to an area to you actually can write to. Since all you're doing it writing `value` to the address given in `port`.
2. In order to store a string at a specified location you will have to instruct the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)).

In any case, it usually starts with an `const char *version = "V1.2AG4ML"` in a separate object (file), that you will put in a region manually via the linker script.

How this is done depends on the toolchain you are using, the manual should provide the info you need.

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by 'area to you actually can write to'? What if it is a flash memory region?

Comment: @ArunJoe Flash memory is not random access write.

Comment: Yeah I know it, I intend to place it in the flash memory so that I can still access it from the bootloader. You mean to say that, I have to make a section in the RAM for this?

Comment: @ArunJoe No, you have to make a section in flash to keep this. Probably an entire block, since that is the minimum erase size.